# How can I exclude all keys with a specific value inside a JSON with jq?

Tags: jq

Let's say I have a JSON like the following:

```
{
    "key1": {
        "keyA": "1",
        "keyB": "null",
        "keyC": "null"
    },
    "key2": {
        "keyA": "null",
        "keyB": "3",
        "keyC": "null"
    }
}
```

I'd like to find a way of excluding all keys with the value `null` on my JSON. So the result would be the following:

```
{
    "key1": {
        "keyA": "1"
    },
    "key2": {
        "keyB": "3"
    }
}
```

I know I can exclude specific keys with their names using `jq`, e.g. `cat myjson.json | jq 'del(.[]|.keyA)'`, this will erase all my `keyA` keys inside the json, but I want to exclude the keys according to their values... How can I exclude all keys with value `"null"` using `jq`?

Comment: Isn't this a bug in the system generating the JSON in the first place?  null values should have been omitted.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm not sure if it's a bug... I have a spatial database with `SpatiaLite` and this database has many `null` values. When I export a part of this database with `ogr2ogr` as a `GeoJSON` file it brings me all null values inside the database in this `GeoJSON` file. So this is a workaround to exclude all irrelevant data and make my JSON as small as possible.

Comment: I'm wondering why it contains the string `"null"` instead of the actual JSON value `null`.

Comment: @chepner Actually it contains the value `null`... Writing the string `"null"` was one typo that I made on the question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
del(..|select(. == "null"))
```

This uses the [recursive-descent operator `..`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..) and [`select` function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) to find all the locations anywhere in the object with values that are equal to `"null"` and gives them to `del`. `select` evaluates a boolean expression to decide whether to include a particular value or not, while `..` gives every single value in the tree to it, and `del` accepts any expression that produces locations, which this does. ([demo](https://mwh.github.io/jqjs/demo.html#del(..%7Cselect(.%20==%20%22null%22))#eyJrZXkxIjp7ImtleUEiOiIxIiwia2V5QiI6Im51bGwiLCJrZXlDIjoibnVsbCJ9LCJrZXkyIjp7ImtleUEiOiJudWxsIiwia2V5QiI6IjMiLCJrZXlDIjoibnVsbCJ9fQ==))

You can use the `path` function to check what it's finding:

```
path(..|select(. == "null"))
```

and debug what it thinks you're trying to delete first. The [output](https://mwh.github.io/jqjs/demo.html#path(..%7Cselect(.%20==%20%22null%22))#eyJrZXkxIjp7ImtleUEiOiIxIiwia2V5QiI6Im51bGwiLCJrZXlDIjoibnVsbCJ9LCJrZXkyIjp7ImtleUEiOiJudWxsIiwia2V5QiI6IjMiLCJrZXlDIjoibnVsbCJ9fQ==) is an array of keys to follow recursively to reach the value, and so the final item in the array is the key that would actually be deleted.

You can also use update-assignment with `|= empty` in jq 1.6 and up (it silently fails in earlier versions). You may or may not find this clearer: `(..|select(. == "null")) |= empty` ([demo](https://mwh.github.io/jqjs/demo.html#(..%7Cselect(.%20==%20%22null%22))%20%7C=%20empty#eyJrZXkxIjp7ImtleUEiOiIxIiwia2V5QiI6Im51bGwiLCJrZXlDIjoibnVsbCJ9LCJrZXkyIjp7ImtleUEiOiJudWxsIiwia2V5QiI6IjMiLCJrZXlDIjoibnVsbCJ9fQ==)) deletes those same keys.

---

If your values are true `null`s, rather than the string `"null"`, you can use the `nulls` builtin function in place of the whole `select`: `del(..|nulls)`.

If your values are true nulls *and* you're using **jq 1.5** (the current version in many distributions), you'll need to use `recurse(.[]?; true)` in place of `..`. This is because null values are specifically excluded from `..` (because [it's defined as `recurse`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#..), which [is defined as](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#recurse(f),recurse,recurse(f;condition),recurse_down) `recurse(.[]?)`, which is defined as `recurse(.[]?; . != null)`). This behaviour changed to the (more useful) one above in 1.6, though [the documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#recurse(f),recurse,recurse(f;condition),recurse_down) hasn't changed, which [appears to be a documentation bug](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2036).

Comment: Thanks... I'm not sure if I caught an edge case but when I use `del(..|select(. == null))` on the json from my application it seems that the recursivity is not working. I'm struggling here trying to figure out why the select is not working on [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZIk4IVhe-8bePmyoAt4QIcZhs5-Pn4TB/view?usp=sharing). Weird thing is that when I create a simple json file with an array of objects inside my objects it works fine. Would you know to explain why the recursivity doesn't work with this json file? ( in this case it's `null` instead of `"null"`)

Comment: @raylight If you're running jq 1.5, `..` *excludes* true null values from consideration. You can replace `..` with [`recurse(.[]?;true)`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#recurse(f),recurse,recurse(f;condition),recurse_down) and it should work - `..` works in 1.6 (though the documentation actually still [says](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#RecursiveDescent:..) it [shouldn't](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#recurse(f),recurse,recurse(f;condition),recurse_down)). You can also simplify `select(.==null)` to just the `nulls` builtin.

Comment: Thanks again! You're right, I'm using jq 1.5 and `cat file.json | jq 'del(recurse(.[]?;true)|select(. == null))'` worked for me... I realized that when I put my json on your demo page the command with `del(..|select(. == null))` works fine, so the difference here is the version.

Comment: Great! I actually did not know this had changed, and always thought it had worked the new way. The explicit `recurse(.[]?;true)` will continue to work after any future upgrade to 1.6 anyway, so you won't need to update anything. And to be fair, the demo page is an independent in-browser reimplementation, so it's not definitive (just convenient for live editing), but it does match the current version's behaviour here.

Comment: @MichaelHomer they [fixed the docs](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/pull/2744/files#diff-e54ccb810ffbe35b34ac1e33a2c2d9fc35cbe976df323b6ee410083e9e7b4e1fR1887)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you know you want to test the values at the 2nd level:

```bsh
jq 'del(.[][] | select(. == "null"))' file
```

This deletes every key-value pair on the 2nd level from the top, where the value is the literal string `null`.

Given the document in the question, this produces the expected output.

Using a version of `jq` newer than 1.5, you could also just update the data to the bits that don't have the `null` value:

```bsh
jq '.[][] |= select(. != "null")' file
```

Comment: Note that the last approach is also jq 1.6-only because it relies on the new "empty RHS means delete" update-assignment behaviour. It will fill your object with nulls on earlier versions. The first version works everywhere.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Thanks. I don't have an older version to test with at the moment, but I'll insert a caveat in the text about this.

Comment: The jq 1.5 result is `{
  "key1": {
    "keyC": null
  },
  "key2": {
    "keyA": null,
    "keyB": null,
    "keyC": null
  }
}` (I actually don't understand where the keys have gone in the first subobject there).

Comment: @MichaelHomer Huh. And I wonder why `keyC` was the one not deleted? Anyway...